# Debian Jessie with Xfce: cannot change locale (LANG) after installing new locale

Tags: unicode, debian, locale

I am running Debian Jessie with xfce.

I used to have the system in English (`en_US.utf8` as `LANG` since I installed debian only with English).

Lately, I installed new locales and even if I made sure I chose `None` for the `default locale`, [as advised on the wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale), I noticed that one of the installed locale, German is now set (`LANG=de_DE.utf8` when I run `locale`).

I followed [the instructions on the other wiki about changing the locale](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale), ie.

`# export=en_US.utf8`

and then

`dpkg-reconfigure locales`

and then restarting.

But I still get `LANG=de_DE.utf8` and `de_DE.utf8` for all the `LC_*` variables (`LANGUAGE` is set to English though).

I even removed the German local, rerun the `export` and `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and restarted but I still have `LANG=de_DE.utf8`.

What am I missing here?

Could it come from xfce `session and startup` settings? I looked a bit there but I'm not sure if I might not break other stuff by playing around with those settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate to this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167794/how-to-change-language-interface-in-xfce

Answer (score 0):

you are using a wrong order:

```
export=en_US.utf-8
```

this should be:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

or:

```
export LANG=en_US.utf-8
```

Anyway, as the Debian wiki says, the use of LC_ALL is discouraged as it only lasts while session (i.e: an open terminal session). You could add it to a startup script, but this is discouraged again by Debian's wiki.

If you just want to change your locale definitely, you must add your desired locale to */etc/locale.gen*. After that, run:

```
locale-gen
```

and after that, verify the recently generated locale with:

```
locale -a
```

*en_US.utf-8* should appear as an output of that order.

Good luck!